# How to use already existing information in three different forms + default values

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-foundation, form, default-value

I have three forms, one for new membership, one for changing your membership information and one for continuing your membership.

In new membership form you give your basic information; name, phone etc. Is there a way to use this information in the other forms, in a different way than the usual click-on-the-link and change?

More like to choose in the other form from a dropdown field the old information (name and social security number, the most important ones) and then change the ending day of your membership.

And my other problem is this. Theres is this column in my list called Type, I would like to it to work this way: when you create a new membership, it shows in the column "new membership", and when continuing your membership it would say "contienued membership". Is it possible to make it print it automatically, without having to select from dropdown select the value.

So New Membership -form would automatically print "New Membership" and Continue Membership -form would print "Continued Membership".

Comment: What type of form are we talking about? InfoPath? And what version of SharePoint are you using? This information will help you get more attention to your question (you can add it as tags)

Comment: Sharepoint Foundation, the end of the forms is .aspx, hopefully that helps a little. Had to look up whole InfoPath..

Comment: Is it 2010, 2013?

Comment: It is 2010 version

Comment: OK, I have added 2010 as a tag on the post